# How can I display files that have been saved as a Buffer?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, buffer, electron

I am saving files as Buffers in my mongo database (using mongoose, nodejs, electron). For now, I'm keeping it simple with text-only files. I read a file in using

```
fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {console.log(err);}
    typeof callback == "function" && callback(data);
});
```

Then I create a new file in my database using the `data` variable. And, now I have something that looks like `BinData(0,"SGVsbG8gV29ybGQK")` stored in my mongodb. All is fine so far.

Now, what if I wanted to display that file in the UI? In this case, in Electron? I think there are two steps.

**Step 1** The first is bringing this variable out of the DB and into the front-end. FYI: The model is called `File` and the variable that stores the file contents is called `content`.

So, I've tried `File.content.toString()` which gives me `Object {type: "Buffer", data: Array[7]}` which is not the string I'm expecting. What is happening here? I read [here](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) that this should work.

**Step 2** Display this file. Now, since I'm only using text files right now, I can just display the string I get once Step 1 is working. But, is there a good way to do this for more complex files? Images and GIFs and such?

Answer (score 0):

You should save the file mime.

And then set response.header MIME

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");

response.write(binary)

response.end()
```

Comment: So there's no responses since this is an electron app, not a web app. Where else can this be done?

Comment: Tell your app About File MIME and Buffer.    {type: "Buffer", data: Array[7]}  data is Buffer array.  use Buffer.concat(data) to get a Buffer You need.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the read buffers into readable stream like below and then send to response

```
function streamToBuffer(readableStream) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const chunks = [];
      readableStream.on("data", (data) => {
          chunks.push(data instanceof Buffer ? data : Buffer.from(data));
      });
      readableStream.on("end", async() => {
          resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks));
      });
      readableStream.on("error", reject);
  });
}

const imageBuffer = await streamToBuffer(fileReadResponse)

response.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
response.write(imageBuffer)
response.end()
```